# Function error for List<String>: 'a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter'

Tags: c#

I have tried to set up a dynamic code that check how many cores there are in the system. I think I have set up it correct where I start a Task for each core and then wait for all tasks to complete.

Now as seen, each Task will return "list1[i]" and "list2[i]" as in:

```
out list1[i], out list2[i]
```

But this error is shown for the above:

**"a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"**

I have been aware of this problem from other code I have written that it is not possible to return into an index like that.

As I try to write a dynamic code that take into account how many cores there are in the system. How would it be possible to do what I am trying to do instead of having for example 24 hardcoded lists if the system have 24 cores?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(runthreads).Start();
}
void runthreads()
{
    int nrCores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    List<List<String>> list1 = new List<List<String>>(); List<List<String>> completelist1 = new List<List<String>>();
    List<List<String>> list2 = new List<List<String>>(); List<List<String>> completelist2 = new List<List<String>>();
    Task[] tasks = new Task[nrCores];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrCores; i++)
    {
        //Add lists
        list1.Add(new List<String>());
        list2.Add(new List<String>());

        //Start Task
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => onefunction(1, 2, out list1[i], out list2[i]));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks); //Wait for all Tasks to complete

    //Now add all lists to completelists
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        completelist1.AddRange(list1[i]);
        completelist2.AddRange(list2[i]);
    }
}
void onefunction(int num1, int num2, out List<String> list1, out List<String> list2)
{
    //Example code for the function!
    list1 = new List<String>(); list2 = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        list1.Add("1");
        list2.Add("2");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use out with an array index. You already know exactly how many items there are so an array would be possible. Even then, a simpler alternative would probably be to return the lists from the method as a tuple or properties in a class.

Comment: That sounds like good news. I am quite bad when it comes to arrays. I really always use Lists and are not quite sure how to declare this if an Array would be a good alternative?

Comment: I don't see why you need `out` at all? Why not create the lists outside of the function and let `onefunction` populate them?

Comment: If I declare a global list like that I think the lists will need a lock object when .Add to them to not get mixed up by all threads and a lock object would slow down the code as speed is important in this case.

Comment: The simplest way would be to make the parameters no longer `out`. The caller creates the empty lists, and `onefunction` fills them in.

Comment: @Raymond Chen That sounds good but I am not sure how to do it or how you mean exactly? I think I should not use any global lists as I then will need a lock object that will be a bottleneck.

Comment: `... => onefunction(1, 2, list1[i], list2[i])`. Remove `out` from the `onefunction` parameter declaration, and remove the `list1 = new List<String>(); list2 = new List<String>();` from the body. It seemed pointless that the original created all these lists and then threw them away. Use them!

Comment: @Raymond Chen That is great I did not think of that. That is a very clean solution! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I want to add that you are not using tasks for what they are meant to. If you want to process stuff in parallel taking the processor cores (and load) into account use the `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` methods. This would also simply your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do an approach using Arrays. Can someone confirm that this is a valid approach or if I miss something or something could be done in a faster way.

For example if this is the fastest way or if this is a bottleneck as speed is important. I could only think of do .ToArray() but wonder if that do "double" work instead of doing something more clean by adding directly to the arrays instead of convert from a list?
***(Notice that I will later not know how many elements to add to the arrays)***

```js
array1 = list1.ToArray();
```

**Complete code:**

```js
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(runthreads).Start();
        }
        void runthreads()
        {
            int nrCores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            String[][] array1 = new String[nrCores][];
            String[][] array2 = new String[nrCores][];

            List<String> completelist1 = new List<String>();
            List<String> completelist2 = new List<String>();
            Task[] tasks = new Task[nrCores];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrCores; i++)
            {
                //Start Task
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => onefunction(1, 2, out array1[i], out array2[i]));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks); //Wait for all Tasks to complete

            //Now add all lists to completelists
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                completelist1.AddRange(array1[i]);
                completelist2.AddRange(array2[i]);
            }
        }
        
        void onefunction(int num1, int num2, out String[] array1, out String[] array2)
        {
            //Example code for the function!
            List<String> list1 = new List<String>(); List<String> list2 = new List<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                list1.Add("1");
                list2.Add("2");
            }
            array1 = list1.ToArray();
            array2 = list2.ToArray();
        }
```